# Why is setting an array of characters to NULL illegal? Passing to function changes behavior

Tags: c

The name of an array is a synonym for the address of the first element of the array, so why can't this address be set to NULL? Is it a language rule to prevent a memory leak?

Also, when we pass an array to a function, it's behavior changes and it becomes possible to set it to NULL.

I don't understand why this occurs. I know it has something to do with pointers, but I just can't wrap my mind around it.

Example:

```
void some_function(char string[]);
int main()
{
    char string[] = "Some string!";
    some_function(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0 ;
}
void some_function(char string[])
{
    string = NULL;
}
```

> Output: Some string!

I read that when an array is passed into a function, what's actually passed are pointers to each element, but wouldn't the name of the array itself still be a synonym for the address of the first element? Why is setting it to NULL here even allowed, but not in the main function?

Is it at all possible to set an array to NULL?

Comment: `void some_function(string[])` is not valid C.  Please provide a meaningful code sample.

Comment: "The name of an array is a synonym for the address of the first element of the array" - no, it isn't. An array is an array, and the address of its first element is a pointer. However, in a function declaration (and **ONLY there**), `T []` is equivalent with `T *`.

Comment: So, just think of it as a special case. You can set every pointer to NULL, but altough an automatically allocated array like that has some things of a pointer, it´s not the same.

Comment: 1) Array name can not be changed  so has been held as a constant. 2) The copy when you pass the address of the array as a pointer is created.

Comment: And, except for the missing `char`, what´s wrong with the question?

Comment: Please read the C FAQ on arrays and pointers http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: "possible to set an array to NULL" --> it is just as easy to set an array to NULL as any other selected value.  Neither are possible.

Answer (score 2):

An array is not a pointer - the symbol `string` in your case has attributes of address *and* size whereas a pointer has only an *address* attribute.  Because an array has an address it can be converted to or interpreted as a pointer, and the language supports this implicitly in a number of cases.

When interpreted as a pointer you should consider its type to be `char* const` - i.e. a constant pointer to variable data, so the address cannot be changed.

In the case of passing the array to a function, you have to understand that arrays are not [first class data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in C, and that they are *passed by reference* (i.e. a pointer) - loosing the size information. The pointer passed to the function is *not* the array, but a pointer to the array - it is variable independent of the original array.

You can illustrate what is effectively happening without the added confusion of function call semantics by declaring:

```
char string[] = "Some string!";
char* pstring = string ;
```

then doing:

```
pstring = NULL ;
```

Critically, the original array data cannot just "disappear" while it is in scope (or at all if it were static), the content of the array *is* the variable, whereas a pointer is a variable that refers to data.  A pointer implements *indirection*, and array does not.  When an array is passed to a function, indirection occurs and a pointer to the array is passed rather than a *copy* of the array.

Incidentally, to pass an array (which is not a first class data type) by copy to a function, you must wrap int within a `struct` (`structs` in C *are* first class data types). This is largely down to the original design of C under constraints of systems with limited memory resources and the need to to maintain compatibility with early implementations and large bodies of legacy code.

So the fact that you cannot assign a pointer to an array is hardly the surprising part - because to do so makes little sense.  What is surprising perhaps is the semantics of "passing an array" and the fact that an array is not a first class data type; leading perhaps to your confusion on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rebind an array variable. An array is not a pointer. True, at a low level they are approximately similar, except pointers have no associated dimension / rank information.

You cant assign NULL to the actual array (same scope), but you can assign to a parameter since C treats it like a pointer.

The standard says:

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’,

So in the function the NULL assignment is legal.

Comment: You might need to justify that last statement - I am not sure what you might mean.  Apart from the missing semicolon (which I've fixed), and needing stdio.h included, it is compilable.

Comment: I stand corrected, I didn't believe 'string = NULL' would compile since 'char string[] = NULL` doesn't compile. I revised, after looking at the standard explanation of "array parameters".